# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log{(1+x)}}{x^{2}+1} \ dx $?

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log{(1+x)}}{x^{2}+1} \ dx $$

I tried substituting x with 1/t but couldn't find the answer. Can someone provide any hint?

As many suggested I substituted x with tan t but again I got stuck at
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{4}} \log{(1+tant)} \ dt $$

I finally solved it and got the correct answer.

Comment: $x=\tan \theta$

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hint -

Put $\tan^{-1} x = t$

Then x = tan t.

And $\frac{1}{1 + x^2} dx = dt$

Comment: All downvotes are welcome. But please tell the reason so that I can improve my mistake.

Comment: This is not a ["good" question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Answer (score -2):

Put $\displaystyle x = \frac{1-t}{1+t}$

Comment: This is not a ["good" question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.